# ArcMap - Driving distance between 2 sets of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, origin-destination

I have a question regarding the calculating driving distances between any two points.

I have 2 CSV files, an origin and a destination file, which look like the following:

```
Origin                                    Destination
ID       Latitude     Longitude           ID       Latitude     Longitude
1        33.9425      -118.408,1          15       44.08        -69.05
2        66.0581      -23.1353,2          16       46.41        -68.49
                                          17       44.26        -70.49
```

The goal is to calculate the driving distance between any origin and each destination, i.e., given the two CSV files, the result should contain 6 routes. While I could solve this problem using Google Maps or Mapquest, I tried to go with ArcMap, because the original origin CSV file contains 500 lines, whil the destination file contains around 42.000 lines, building around 20 million routes.

When opening a new project, I choose the "Coterminous United States" map as a map, because all points in both files are located in the United States.

Could it be possible that there are no underlying routes for the Network Analyst to take into account?

If so, how can I generate them?

Importing the data sets worked fine (via File -> Add Data -> Add Data). However, displaying them on the map showed, that there was no object id - so I exported them and re - displayed them on the map, leading to the following points:

[image: Destination Data Set]

According to [this GeoNet answer](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/28614), adding a route should be possible now. However, after activating the Network Analyst, only the "Network Analyst Options" are clickable.

How can I tell the Network Analyst to calculate the distances between both sets?

Answer (score 1):

In the toolbox in ArcMap, in the Network Analyst Tools there is a tool 'Make Route Layer'.  Use this tool to create the routes.

Docs: [Make Route Layer (Network Analyst)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-route-layer.htm)

However, before you can create routes, you need to create your network.  ArcGIS does not do this automatically.  You have to build it.

Docs:  [Overview of the Network Analyst Toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-network-analyst-toolbox.htm)